# Secure cookie and invalid certificate

Tags: security, http, cookies, https

Is a secure cookie supposed to be sent to an HTTPS server that have an invalid certificate? I mean, I have an application served by a HTTPS server which send a cookie with the secure flag activated after the login step. Is my server supposed to receive the cookie back if it has an invalid certificate? Is this is normalized (it seems it's not), could someone point me to the relevant part of the norm?

Comment: In testing with Rails3 and Chrome, if I have a server with a self-signed cert (so the browser warns it is untrusted) then I do not get my secure cookies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a [cookie with *Secure* flag set is only sent for TLS/SSL secured connections](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4):

> If the cookie's secure-only-flag is true, then the request-uri's scheme must denote a "secure" protocol (as defined by the user agent). […] Typically, user agents consider a protocol secure if the protocol makes use of transport-layer security, such as SSL or TLS.  For example, most user agents consider "https" to be a scheme that denotes a secure protocol.

But to establish a TLS/SSL connection, it only matters whether the certificate is trusted. It doesn’t matter how the certificate was trusted, i. e. whether it was trusted automatically or manually.

Answer (score 4):

Whether the certificate is valid or not is actually immaterial.  If an invalid certificate is detected when browsing to a site most browsers will tell the user the cert is invalid and let the user determine whether they want to proceed or not.

With regards to the "secure" part of the cookie, all that does is tell the browser that the cookie is only valid for https connections and shouldn't be transferred over regular http connections.

This means that yes, your server should receive the cookie back from the browser provided that the URL being accessed is an https url.  Even if the server's cert is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There's also this statement in the [RFC 2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965#page-7) which is obsoleted by RFC 6265:

> The user agent (possibly with user interaction) MAY determine what
> level of security it considers appropriate for "secure" cookies.
> The Secure attribute should be considered security advice from the
> server to the user agent, indicating that it is in the session's
> interest to protect the cookie contents.  *When it sends a "secure"
> cookie back to a server, the user agent SHOULD use no less than
> the same level of security as was used when it received the cookie
> from the server*.